# calling Drive REST API Version 3 via URL-fetch in apps script delivers only default attributes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am calling Drive REST API Version 3 via URL-fetch in apps script. I am calling Files list method and query for files. Querying is working, but I only get the default attributes of the files in the api's response. If I am using fields parameter to get more fields it is just ignored.

```
   var retVal =[];
    var baseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files";
    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

    var options = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token},
   }

 var maxResults = 100;

 var params = {
 q: query, 
 pageSize: maxResults,
 fields: 'nextPageToken,incompleteSearch,files(kind,id,name,mimeType,starred,trashed)',
 };

 do {      

  var queryString = Object.keys(params).map(function(p) {
    return [encodeURIComponent(p), encodeURIComponent(params[p])].join("=");
  }).join("&amp;"); 

  var apiUrl = baseUrl + "?" + queryString;

  Logger.log(apiUrl);

  var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch( apiUrl,
  options).getContentText());

  //Logger.log(response);

  response.files.forEach(function(fileObj) {       
    retVal.push(fileObj);
  })

    params['pageToken'] = response.nextPageToken;

 } while (params.pageToken);

 Logger.log(retVal);
 return retVal
```

Encoded Query: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=name%20contains%20%22Test%20%2F%20Blub%2033%22%20and%20not%20mimeType%20%3D%20%22application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%22%20and%20trashed%20%3D%20false&pageSize=100&fields=nextPageToken%2CincompleteSearch%2Cfiles(kind%2Cid%2Cname%2CmimeType%2Cstarred%2Ctrashed)&orderBy=folder%2CmodifiedTime%20desc%2Ctitle&supportsTeamDrives=false&includeTeamDriveItems=false

test results from API: [{kind=drive#file, name=Kopie von Test / Blub 33, id=1oTbd78Bn7R7Xjo6TEAAyZmE5CjwdgRMT, mimeType=application/json}, {kind=drive#file, name=Test / Blub 33, id=12IpttBvSY-Z31ueNqG_Dmb46dXH5udcl, mimeType=application/json}, {kind=drive#file, name=Test / Blub 33, id=1FqKyDFT0bpp1JuAj3WeSV6AL-b12X4vb, mimeType=application/json}]

can someone help why the api is ignoring fields parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `&amp;` with `&` when evaluation the queryString value.

```
var queryString = Object.keys(params).map(function(p) {
   return [encodeURIComponent(p), encodeURIComponent(params[p])].join("=");
}).join("&");
```

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for you answer. If I change source code as suggested I got an http 400 error with invalid value returned. Problem is that I don't get the named attributes of "fields" parameter i(fields: 'nextPageToken,incompleteSearch,files(kind,id,name,mimeType,starred,trashed)',) in the returned object from api.

Comment: Can you share your query?

Comment: Sure: var query = "name contains 'Test 33'"; I think the querz can not be the problem because I get results from api, i just do not got all fields of the file items...

Comment: can no one help?

Comment: Try using fields: "*" to see if all the fields are returned.

Comment: Hi Amit, if I chang object to:  var params = {
     q: query,
     pageSize: maxResults,
     fields: '*' };
I get only attribs kind, id, name and mimeType. Not more. Regards Jochen